# Factory Girl with implicit has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I'm trying to test a model that has an implicit has_many association, and am having some difficulties.

I have a table A, with column B_ID, where B is basically a foreign key - except there is no table B in my database, or an active record class associated with object B. There is also table C that has column a B_ID.

In the model for table C we have:

```
# implicit has_many :alphas
def alphas
   Alpha.where(:b_id => b_id).order(:xyz)
end
```

This database structure makes sense for the data I have, and the non-test code works fine.

My test code almost works, and I hope I am just missing something simple.

I have factories defined for A and C, and I have a test:

```
a1 = Factory(:alpha, :b_id => 123, :xyz => 100)
a2 = Factory(:alpha, :b_id => 123, :xyz => 200)
c1 = Factory(:c, :b_id => 123)

puts c1.alphas.count
puts c1.alphas.first

c1.alphas.first.should == a1
```

The output is:

```
2
nil
<test fails>
```

Changing the number of A objects that share the B_ID result in the c1.alphas.count changing, but I can't seem to actually inside the implicit association and get an A object back - instead I always get nil. There are other methods that in my C model that I can't test because those methods need to access fields on individual A objects.

Does anybody have any insight into what is going behind the scenes here, or what I might do to get around this? Thanks.

Comment: What do you get if you `puts c1.alphas.class.name`?

Comment: @BenLee, ActiveRecord::Relation

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does `puts c1.alphas.to_a[0]` show the record? What about `puts c1.alphas.limit(1).to_a[0]`? I'm just curious if the breakage is in the background automatic loading somehow failing.

Comment: Unfortunately, both output `nil`

Comment: Hmm... have a look at the source code for `ActiveRecord::Relation`: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d22592a05b299c21e30ec8b38890a178dca863b4/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L148. Might lead you to an answer. Two more ideas for debugging: Try `c1.alphas.send(:exec_queries)` and `c1.alphas.loaded?` to see if there is a disconnect in either of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this for an example to have an admin_user with the role of Admin.

https://github.com/drhenner/ror_ecommerce/blob/master/spec/factories/user.rb

In this case roles are not a factory.

I find it best to do this like the following though.

```
  @order = Factory(:order)
  order_item = Factory(:order_item, :total => 5.52 )
  @order.stubs(:order_items).returns([order_item, order_item])
```

or

```
  @order = Factory(:order)
  order_item = Factory(:order_item, :total => 5.52, :order => @order )
```

Comment: Stubbing the association isn't the clean solution I had in mind, but it gets the job done

Comment: So do I delete the answer?  Stack overflow has asked me to.  Yes I should have a disclaimer that I did reference my own code in the link above.  Sorry If I didn't say that before.